# Long-lived multicasting Observable that resubscribes to its source every time it is subscribed to

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I would like to use existing rxjs operators to create a multicasting observable that resubscribes to its source every time it is subscribed to but does not unsubscribe its subscribers when the source completes.

The intent is to have a mix of short-lived and long-lived components that share the same data source. When a new short-lived component is created, the shared data should be updated for both the new component and any long-lived components also subscribed to the data source.

Using Observable.create(), I was able to create a custom observable that produces this behavior but it feels like there is probably an out-of-the box solution that doesn't require writing custom code.

Here's what I have tried.

```
import { of, Observable, Observer, zip, interval, merge } from "rxjs";
import { filter, map, publish, tap, delay, shareReplay, share } from "rxjs/operators";

class MySubject {
  constructor(private observable: Observable<any>) {}

  sourceActive = false;
  subscribers: Array<Observer<any>> = [];

  public subscribe(observer: Observer<any>) {
    this.subscribers.push(observer);

    if (!this.sourceActive) {
      console.log("subscribing");
      this.sourceActive = true;
      this.observable.subscribe(
        x => this.subscribers.forEach(sub => sub.closed || sub.next(x)),
        x => this.subscribers.forEach(sub => sub.closed || sub.error(x)),
        () => this.sourceActive = false
      );
    }
  }
}

const source$ = of(1).pipe(
  tap(x=>console.log("invoked cold")),
  delay(2000)
);
const mySubject = new MySubject(source$);
const super$ = Observable.create(observer => mySubject.subscribe(observer));

const sub1 = super$.subscribe(x => console.log("sub 1"));
const sub2 = super$.subscribe(x => console.log("sub 2"));

setTimeout(x => {
  sub1.unsubscribe();
  super$.subscribe(x => console.log("sub 3"));
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share data between multiple components you must use a Subject.
The Subject emits the changes to all connected subscribers.

or

BehaviorSubject that has notion of the current value executed by the observable and that can be retrieved by new subscribers.

Maybe you must watch a ReplaySubject too.

I hope you find it useful.